# torch/nn - Joining arrays of Tensors element wise

Tags: lua, join, torch

The subject of this question is joining tensors for neural networks with torch/nn and torch/nngraph libraries for Lua. I started coding in Lua a few weeks ago so my experience is very minimal. In the text below, I refer to lua tables as arrays.

## Context

I am working with a recurrent neural network for speech recognition.
At some point in the network there are `N` number of arrays of `m` Tensors.

```
a = {a1, a2, ..., aM},
b = {b1, b2, ..., bM}, 
... N times
```

Where `ai` and `bi` are tensors and `{}` represents an array.

What needs to be done is join all those arrays element-wise so that `output` is an array of `M` Tensors where `output[i]` is the result of joining every ith Tensors from the `N` arrays over the second dimension.

```
output = {z1, z2, ..., zM}
```

#### Example

`||` used to represent Tensors

```
x = {|1 1|, |2 2|}
     |1 1|  |2 2|
     Tensors of size 2x2

y = {|3 3 3|, |4 4 4|}
     |3 3 3|  |4 4 4|
     Tensors of size 2x3
        |
        | Join{x,y}
        \/
z = {|1 1 3 3 3|, |2 2 4 4 4|}
     |1 1 3 3 3|  |2 2 4 4 4|
     Tensors of size 2x5
```

So the first Tensor of `x` of size 2x2 was joined with the first Tensor of `y` of size 2x3 over the second dimension and same thing for second Tensor of each array resulting in `z` an array of Tensors 2x5.

## Problem

Now this is a basic concatenation, but I can't seem  to find a module in the torch/nn library that would allow me to do that. I could write my own module of course, but if an already existing module does it then I would rather go with that.

The only existing module I know that joins table is (obviously) JoinTable. It takes an array of Tensors and joins them together. I want to join arrayS of tensors element-wise.

Also, as we are feeding input to our network, the number of Tensors in the `N` arrays varies, so `m` from the context above is not constant.

## Idea

What I thought I could do in order to use the module JoinTable is convert my arrays into Tensors instead and then `JoinTable` on the converted `N` Tensors. But then again I would need a module that does such a conversion and and another one to convert back to an array in order to feed it to the next layers of the network.

## Last resort

Write a new module that iterates over all given arrays and concatenates element-wise. Of course it's do-able, but the whole purpose of this post is to find a way to avoid writing smelly modules. It seems weird to me that such a module doesn't already exist.

---

## Conclusion

I finally decided to do as I wrote in **Last resort**. I wrote a new module that iterates over all given arrays and concatenates element-wise.

Though, the answer given by @fmguler does the same without having to write a new module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with nn.SelectTable and nn.JoinTable like this;

```
require 'nn'

x = {torch.Tensor{{1,1},{1,1}}, torch.Tensor{{2,2},{2,2}}}
y = {torch.Tensor{{3,3,3},{3,3,3}}, torch.Tensor{{4,4,4},{4,4,4}}}

res = {}
res[1] = nn.JoinTable(2):forward({nn.SelectTable(1):forward(x),nn.SelectTable(1):forward(y)})
res[2] = nn.JoinTable(2):forward({nn.SelectTable(2):forward(x),nn.SelectTable(2):forward(y)})

print(res[1])
print(res[2])
```

If you want this to be done in a module, wrap it in nnGraph;

```
require 'nngraph'

x = {torch.Tensor{{1,1},{1,1}}, torch.Tensor{{2,2},{2,2}}}
y = {torch.Tensor{{3,3,3},{3,3,3}}, torch.Tensor{{4,4,4},{4,4,4}}}

xi = nn.Identity()()
yi = nn.Identity()()
res = {}
--you can loop over columns here>>
res[1] = nn.JoinTable(2)({nn.SelectTable(1)(xi),nn.SelectTable(1)(yi)})
res[2] = nn.JoinTable(2)({nn.SelectTable(2)(xi),nn.SelectTable(2)(yi)})
module = nn.gModule({xi,yi},res)

--test like this
result = module:forward({x,y})
print(result)
print(result[1])
print(result[2])

--gives the result
th> print(result)
{
  1 : DoubleTensor - size: 2x5
  2 : DoubleTensor - size: 2x5
}

th> print(result[1])
 1  1  3  3  3
 1  1  3  3  3
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2x5]

th> print(result[2])
 2  2  4  4  4
 2  2  4  4  4
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 2x5]
```

Comment: Awesome, did not think of that.

Comment: Just need to add some kind of loops to have a variable number of arrays such as x and y and a variable number of tensors in the arrays.
Though it becomes kind of complicated for a simple task. I chose this as the accepted answer as it answers my need of not writing a new module (which I ended doing in the end).